# Add a Trailing Slash to URL with React HashRouter

Tags: reactjs, react-router

My React app has the following render definition

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={ createStoreWithMiddleware(RootReducer) }>
    <HashRouter>
        <App />
    </HashRouter>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('react')
)
```

All URLs look as such

```
http://localhost:8080/myApp#/dashboard
http://localhost:8080/myApp#/about
```

I want to add a trailing slash before the `#` so the URLs look a *little* less ugly, like so

```
http://localhost:8080/myApp/#/dashboard
http://localhost:8080/myApp/#/about
```

Any ideas on how to do so?

Comment: This page may help you: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3/docs/guides/Histories.md#hashhistory

Comment: have you tried changing the context url for your web server that serves the file?
@vahdet that page is for the docs for v3, not v4.

Comment: @nbkhope you're right and your suggestion also makes sense. I am going to share the v4's HashRouter documents then: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/HashRouter

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following method:

```
import {  Router } from "react-router-dom";
import {
    createBrowserHistory
} from 'history';

const history = createBrowserHistory({
    basename: '/admin/#/'
});
```

Please note that I used normal Router and created browser history. Why? Cuz if I had used HashRouter it would append another # in the URL.

After this, make sure to use the base url as `/admin/` everywhere else **Especially when using for Redirect route inside Switch**

Then add this history to the Route as follows:

```
<Router history={history} >
  <OtherComponentsOrRoutes />
</Router>
```

In `Switch` of the `Routes`, you can put redirect like this:

```
<Route exact path="/admin/" render={() => (<Redirect to="/dashboard" />)} />
```

Why? Because we have set the base url in createBrowserHistory as '/admin/'.

This solution works. Please try it out. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I accomplished this by adding the following logic to my root-level parent component constructor. This component contains the Hash Router, so the constructor is called before the Hash Router is even invoked:

```
const history = require('myHistory');
const {HashRouter, Route, Switch} = require('react-router-dom');
```

...

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    if(document.location.pathname[document.location.pathname.length-1] !== '/') {
      // kinda hacky way to get the sexy /#/ url instead of just #/
      history.replace(document.location.pathname+'/#');
    }
  }
```

... and my render:

```
render() {
    return (
      <HashRouter history={history}>
        <div>
          <Switch>
            ...
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </HashRouter>
    );
  }
```