# Insert a slash before hash in react HashRouter

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, react-router, weblogic

I have a spring-boot + react application, that's after a painful process, is now deployed in a weblogic server.

So there's a final issue to everything works fine. When I access the application the url is something like

`server.com/root#/route`

And sometimes the screen doesn't load but if I, manually forces the url to:

`server.com/root/#/route`

Everything works fine. Is there anyway to enforce HashRouter or other react or weblogic component to add this slash before hash?

Comment: Please provide with the code . Also, why is there a '#' in your URL  ?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to say thta I'm using HashRouter in react, It includes the # in url,I've updated the question tittle to inform this.

Comment: maybe this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59688958